# How to insert text into Outlook email editor using VBA

Tags: vba, email, outlook, ms-word

I wish to create a macro that inserts the date into an email body which **is currently open for editing, prior to sending**.

I am using Outlook 2013 on a Windows 7 machine.

Desired workflow:

- Click reply to an email
- Within the email editor, place the text cursor within email body for desired position to insert text
- Execute the macro (by clicking on an icon in the email editor window's quick access toolbar). Macro will insert the date.

(Assume the date has been stored as a string variable, i.e. the macro simply inserts a variable into the email body at a desired position).

All Outlook VBA examples I have found for inserting text into an email body involve storing the active email's HTMLBody as a string, appending the desired text to that string, then creating a brand new email, and re-populating the to, cc, bcc, subject and htmlbody. I wish to avoid this, as it seems very clunky.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*[InsertBefore Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa212203(v=office.11).aspx)* or *[InsertAfter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192427.aspx)*

*[Inspector.WordEditor Property (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196.aspx)*

*[Application.ActiveInspector Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863939.aspx)*

Example

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection
        

    Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
    Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor
    Set Selection = wdDoc.Application.Selection
        Selection.InsertBefore Format(Now, "DD/MM/YYYY")
    
    
    Set Inspector = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set Selection = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

> [image]

---

***Reference to Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library***

---

> *Go to Outlook VBA editor either by pressing **`"Alt + F11"`** keys or clicking on the **`"Visual Basic"`** button in the “Developer” ribbon.*
>
> - ***1.** In VBA editor window, click the "Tools" button in the menu bar.*
> - ***2.** Then, from the drop down list, select the "References" option.*
>
> [image]
>
> - ***3.** In the dialog box, you can pull the scrolling bar down until you locate what you want, such as "Microsoft Word XX.X Object Library".*
>
> [image]