# Copy Excel range as Picture to Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How can I use the command "Paste Special - As Picture" that you access in Excel from the right-click menu?

I have viewed various posts, but they seem to be outdated when using Excel 2016. It seems it has to be in this section,

```
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
```

How do I alter to allow copy and paste as picture?

When using the original code below, I lose all column and row sizing in the email body.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim outMail As Object

Set rng = Nothing
' Only send the visible cells in the selection.

Set rng = Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B4:L17").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With outMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set outMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' By Ron de Bruin.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*To get better picture on Outlook, work with [Word object model with MailItem.GetInspector Property (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-getinspector-property-outlook)*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim Email As Object
    Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document

    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
    Set rng = Sht.Range("B4:L17")
        rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor

    With Email
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName

         wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture

'        if need setup inlineshapes hight & width
         With wdDoc
            .InlineShapes(1).Height = 130
         End With

        .Display
    End With

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set Email = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error: "Compile Error: User-defined type not defined." on this part of the code: 

'Dim wdDoc As Word.Document'

Do I need to add any particular reference in VBA to allow this code to work?

Comment: @linktheory Yes, you will have to add reference to `Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library`.

Comment: @0m3r Is there a way to keep the image and still allow content (text, etc.) to be present in the body of the e-mail?

Comment: @linktheory Yes, you will have to set the destination on the [`Range Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/range-object-word)

Comment: @L42 are you saying range.body(“body of text”)? This is still new to me so I am not entirely sure where this would be placed.

Comment: @linktheory Try `wdDoc.Range.InsertAfter "Hello 0m3r"` after `wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture` look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662697/4539709 the benefit of adding reference to Outlook Library is you will have access to all Word Objects - you may wanna post new question and we will help fix it- thanks

Comment: @linktheory see here another example using Paragraphs https://stackoverflow.com/a/49104427/4539709

Comment: @Om3r - if you ever get bored, here is another [email question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65396620/6706419) that I think would be of interest. You seem to provide best solutions relating to Outlook so figured id share with you. I was able to provide a workaround solution but curious if you know the actual problem

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Dim ol As Object 'Outlook.Application
Dim olEmail As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
Dim olInsp As Object 'Outlook.Inspector
Dim wd As Object 'Word.Document

Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B4:L17").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Set ol = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") '/* if outlook is running, create otherwise */
Set olEmail = ol.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

With olEmail
    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    If olInsp.EditorType = 4 Then 'olEditorWord
        Set wd = olInsp.WordEditor
        wd.Range.PasteAndFormat 13 'wdChartPicture
    End If
    .Display
End With
```

If sure that your version of Outlook uses Word Editor, you can do it like:

```
With olEmail
    .GetInspector.WordEditor.Range.PasteAndFormat 13
    .Display
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add Text, use this code.

```
Dim ol As Object 'Outlook.Application
Dim olEmail As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
Dim olInsp As Object 'Outlook.Inspector
Dim wd As Object 'Word.Document

Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B4:L17").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Set ol = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") '/* if outlook is running, create otherwise */
Set olEmail = ol.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

With olEmail
    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    If olInsp.EditorType = 4 Then 'olEditorWord
        Set wd = olInsp.WordEditor
        wd.Range.PasteAndFormat 13 'wdChartPicture
    End If

    wd.Paragraphs(1).Range.InsertAfter "Hi, There" & Chr(10)

    Sheets("chart").Range("B4:L17").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    wd.Paragraphs(wd.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Characters.First.PasteAndFormat 13
    wd.Paragraphs.Add

    Sheets("chart").Range("B4:L17").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    wd.Paragraphs(wd.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Characters.First.PasteAndFormat 13
    wd.Paragraphs.Add

    wd.Paragraphs(wd.Paragraphs.Count).Range.InsertAfter Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "BR"

    .Display
End With
```