# Pasting Chart into Outlook Email from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

Tried all other codes on similar pages but failed to work.

This is my current version. Works only if I currently have a new email window open and oddly, my code will paste the .body and cell range details into 2 separate new email windows.

I just want the code to open a new email window with contents .body and cell range details (contains chart). Anybody have any ideas where my code went wrong?

```
Sub pasting01()

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
.TO = "xyz@anc.com"
.CC = "abc@xyz.com"
.Subject = "Test"
.Body = "Dear Mr Lee" & vbNewLine

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J30").Copy
Set vInspector = OutMail.GetInspector
Set wEditor = vInspector.WordEditor

wEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
wEditor.Application.Selection.End = wEditor.Application.Selection.Start

wEditor.Application.Selection.Paste

.display

End With

On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48897439/4539709

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You have some errors on your code, try using **Option Explicit** top of your module*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub pasting01()
    Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sht.Range("A1:J30")
        rng.Copy

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    Dim vInspector As Object
    Set vInspector = OutMail.GetInspector

    Dim wEditor As Object
    Set wEditor = vInspector.WordEditor

    With OutMail
        .TO = "xyz@anc.com"
        .CC = "abc@xyz.com"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .display

         wEditor.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = "Dear Mr Lee" & vbCr

         wEditor.Paragraphs(2).Range.Paste

    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much the code works perfectly with option explicit!

Answer (score 1):

Can you mess about with the following to suit your purpose?

```
Option Explicit

Sub pasting01()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    Dim myChart As Chart
    Set myChart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart

    Dim myPicture As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim myPath As String

    myPicture = "Chart1.png"
    myPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\"

    fileName = myPath & myPicture
    myChart.Export fileName

    With OutMail

        .TO = "xyz@anc.com"
        .CC = "abc@xyz.com"
        .Subject = "Test"
        .Body = "Dear Mr Lee" & vbNewLine
        .Attachments.Add fileName
        .HTMLBody = "<html><p>First Line... </p>" & _
                    "<img src=cid:" & Replace(myPicture, " ", "%20") & " height=2*240 width=2*180>" & _
                                                        "<p>Salutation</p>" & _
                                                        "<p>" & "More text" & "</p></html>"
        .Display

    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    Kill fileName

End Sub
```

Result:

[image: Output]