# Copying a certain cell range and pasting in outlook mail body

Tags: excel, vba

**My Questions:**

Is there any way to copy a cell range and paste it in the outlook mail body programatically?

I have this code, but it doesn't seem to copy the cell range, but if you type in an individual cell (ex. A4), it's able to copy it.

```
Sub Email()
   Dim xOutApp As Object
   Dim xOutMail As Object
   Dim xMailBody As String
   Dim szTodayDate As String
   szTodayDate = Format(Date, "mm.dd.yyyy")
   On Error Resume Next
   Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
   xMailBody = ActiveSheet.Range("A4:B4").Value
              On Error Resume Next
  With xOutMail
    .To = "tryemail@gmail.com"
    .CC = "tryemail2@gmail.com"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Schedule for deal pursuit" & " " & szTodayDate
    .Body = xMailBody
    .Display   'or use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set xOutMail = Nothing
Set xOutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying range including formatting when pasting in Outlook email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163778/copying-range-including-formatting-when-pasting-in-outlook-email-body)

Answer (score 0):

That's the only idea I had .. using a loop to add every cell value to the bodyMail ..

```
         xMailBody = ""
        ' i represents the columns
        For i = 1 To 2
             xMailBody = xMailBody & " " & ActiveSheet.Cells(4, i).Value
        Next i
```