# Pasting Excel Range as Image

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to paste several Excel ranges as images on Outlook body.

I have this code working, but when i paste the image it erase the `.HTMLBody` that I have already written inside the email body.

How do I keep the `HTMLBody` paste the image after.

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A1:U49")
r.Copy

'Open a new mail item
Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set outMail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = outMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

'Get its Word editor

With outMail
    .display
    .HTMLBody = "<p>Boa tarde,</p>" & _
    "<p>Segue abaixo para acompanhamento <strong>gerencial</strong> dos ritmos de opera&ccedil;&otilde;es.</p>" & _
    "<p>Essa visibilidade di&aacute;ria &eacute; importante para medir como estamos em rela&ccedil;&atilde;o ao plano (IBP-S&amp;OP) e a capacidade informada.</p>" & _
    "<p><em>LEGENDA </em></p>"

End With

wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying range including formatting when pasting in Outlook email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163778/copying-range-including-formatting-when-pasting-in-outlook-email-body)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*the issue is you're replace the `htmlbody` with `wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture`*

*Looks like you have multiple paragraphs on your `HTMLBody` so work with **[Paragraphs Object (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/paragraphs-object-word).** The Paragraphs property return the Paragraphs collection `Paragraphs(1)` or `(2)` and so on then decide where to place the image.*

*Example*

> ```
> wordDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture
> ```

*By using the paragraphs collection you will be working with current `HTMLBody` and keep your signature, etc ...*