# Copy/Paste Range of cells as picture in Outlook email with text in body

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a range of cells into an Outlook template that has a message in the body.

```vb
Sub SendEmail_Class_Name()

Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A1:AA3")
r.Copy

Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application
Dim Source As String
Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application

Dim EmailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

EmailItem.To = "Name@gmail.com"
EmailItem.CC = "Name1@gmail.com; Name2@gmail.com;" & _
                "Name3@gmail.com; Name4@gmail.com"
EmailItem.Subject = "Test Email From Excel VBA"
EmailItem.HTMLBody = "Hey,<p>" & "Seeing if this Macro will send an Email<p>" & _
                    "Thanks,<p>"
Source = ThisWorkbook.FullName
EmailItem.Attachments.Add Source

EmailItem.Display
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = EmailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor

wordDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat wdChartPicture

End Sub
```

The code pulls up the template with the To, CC, and Subject but the message in the body will not appear only the picture of the cells.
I tried putting the picture before the code for the message and only the message will appear and not the picture.

How do I order my code so that both the message and picture appear in the body of the email?

Comment: Check out my simple sample on Copy and pasting excel ranges into outlook
[Copy xl to outlook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCBgPhnXnvk)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pasting Excel Range as Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49521170/pasting-excel-range-as-image)

Comment: @Davesexcel I formatted your code to fit mine and it is working. Thank you