# How to add text at the beginning of every email?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to add a text at the beginning of every email sent through Outlook. I found some examples but none add the text at the specific beginning of email.

I would like to add a confidential mark at the very beginning of email. It would be something like this:

BEFORE sending email:

> Dear Tom,
> Please send the reports

AFTER:

> [CONFIDENTIAL]
> Dear Tom,
> Please send the reports

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662697/4539709

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This worked. Thanks, quite useful it does what I was looking for. I added additional code to move the cursor to beginning of email.

```
'Set cursor to beggining
Dim Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim Range As Word.Range
Dim Pos As Long
Dim Selection As Word.Selection
Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector
Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor
If Not wdDoc Is Nothing Then
    Pos = wdDoc.Range.Start
    Set Range = wdDoc.Range(Pos, Pos)
    Range.Select
End If
Set Inspector = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing
'ADD TEXT MARK
Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor
Set Selection = wdDoc.Application.Selection
    Selection.InsertAfter Format("[CONFIDENTIAL]" & Chr(13))
Set Inspector = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set Selection = Nothing
```