# VBA Runtime error 91 / 4605 when no Email was opened before

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I have a code in Excel that copy a table to a new Email:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TESTEMAIL()

Const olMailItem As Long = 0

    Dim StrFile, signature As String
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim Outmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set Outmail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim myRecipient As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Outmail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Set OutApp = Nothing

Outmail.Display
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = Outmail.GetInspector.WordEditor

Range("A1:E10").Copy

Dim p1 As Picture
Set p1 = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste
p1.Cut


With wordDoc.Application.Selection

    .Start = Len(Outmail.Body)      ' error n° 91 
    .End = .Start
    .PasteSpecial wdPasteBitmap     ' Error n° 4605 or Error n°91

End With

End Sub
```

The code returns an error every first time I use it after starting the computer:

> Error Code 91 "*Object variable or With block variable not set*"

It is most of the time when Outlook wasn't opened before or when no new email was opened before.

Sometimes I also get the error code 4605, saying that the document is locked against modifications.
The 2 Errors are coming at the end and are marked in the code. (error can happen on 2 different lines)

Sometimes everything worked but only when a new email was opened in Outlook before, (event if Outlook is closed).

Any clue why that might be and how to solve the problem?

Comment: You already have a reference `wordDoc` which holds the message content, so you should use that instead of  `Outmail.Body`.  If you have problems pasting as picture, then you can try instead using the `Range.CopyPicture` method to copy the Excel content.

Comment: What are you trying to do? you have set `Set OutApp = Nothing` then `
Outmail.Display` you have multiple `OutApp`

Comment: @Tim Williams `worddoc` doesn't return the same as `Outmail.Body` and I changed to `Range.Copypicture`, but it still doesn't work and the picture isn't as clear.

Comment: @0m3r I have taken `Set OutApp = Nothing` out, no difference with the issue. 
I am trying to paste a range as picture in an Email, but somehow it doesn't work when Outlook had no Email opened already.

Comment: See answer below, let me know it if worked for you.

Comment: @0m3r I started to check yesterday, it is quite close but I will check again this afternoon before commenting/upvoting (though I upvoted your related answer :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is this what you are trying to do?*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TESTEMAIL()
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim Outmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set Outmail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Set wordDoc = Outmail.GetInspector.WordEditor

    Dim Sht As Excel.Worksheet
    Set Sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sht.Range("A1:E10")
        rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    With Outmail
        .To = "0m3r@email.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Hello"
        .Display

         wordDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
                                       DataType:=wdPasteBitmap, _
                                       Placement:=wdFloatOverText, _
                                       DisplayAsIcon:=False


         wordDoc.Paragraphs(1).SpaceAfter = 20 ' add space to 12 points

         wordDoc.Range.InsertBefore "Hello 0m3r" & vbCr

         wordDoc.Paragraphs(1).SpaceAfter = 20 ' add space to 12 points


    End With

End Sub
```

*[Make sure to Reference to Microsoft Word & Outlook xx.x Object Library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662697/4539709)*

*[MSDN Paragraphs.SpaceAfter property (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Paragraphs.SpaceAfter)*

*[MSDN Range.PasteAndFormat method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.pasteandformat)*

*[MSDN PasteAndFormat Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa220334(v=office.11))*

*[MSDN WdPasteDataType enumeration (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdpastedatatype)*

Comment: The issue is that my entire code is adding a short text (typed in the code) , then this picture and then the signature. By adapting your code I come to a similar issue.
Also the picture I get with this method is different (less clear) from the picture I was getting with my code... Finally I still don't understand how my code brings an issue only when Outlook didn't have a new Email opened before...

Comment: @Pierre44 If you like `wdPasteBitmap` I have updated the code, also see how to add text. I have added more links to help you  out

Comment: Well it was exactly what I wanted to do, I updated my code thanks to your links and some additionnal researches. (so I upvoted you). However it doesn't explain why this issue comes up and how to exactly solve the error... but I don't need this anymore :)