# How to send only visible cells in email?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The VBA code below sends email with a specific range in body.

Despite selecting only visible cells, I receive all cells.

It seems `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select` does not work.

```vb
Sub VBA_AUTO_MAIL()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1")
        
    Dim lr As Integer
    lr = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
    sh.Range("A1:H" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    ThisWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With Selection.Parent.MailEnvelope.Item
        .to = sh.Range("L6").Value
        .cc = sh.Range("L8").Value
        .Subject = sh.Range("L9").Value
        .attachments.Add "C:\Users\test\Desktop\TEST VBA\TEST_VBA.txt"
        .send
    End With

End Sub
```

I expect only visible columns in email body but I receive all columns.

Comment: This might help you: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm

Comment: Hi @Dean, thank you for link but unfortunately I am not specialist in VBA :( Could help me make some change in my code?

Comment: Are yo u selecting the cells that you would like to paste in email body?

Comment: @0m3r what do you mean?

Comment: Is it OK if I rewrite the whole code?

Comment: @0m3r - Sure! I will be gratefull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Try the following*

```
Option Explicit
Sub VBA_AUTO_MAIL()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1")

    Dim lr As Long
    lr = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = sh.Range("A1:H" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rng.Copy

    Dim olApp As Object
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim Email As Object
    Set Email = olApp.CreateItem(0)

    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Set wdDoc = Email.GetInspector.WordEditor

    With Email
        .To = sh.Range("L6").Value
        .CC = sh.Range("L8").Value
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = sh.Range("L9").Value
        '.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\test\Desktop\TEST VBA\TEST_VBA.txt"

        .Display
         wdDoc.Range.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdChartPicture
        .Send
     End With

End Sub
```

***Make sure to Reference Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library***

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662697/4539709