# Detect an open Outlook email and add to .to field

Tags: vba, email, outlook, ms-word

I've written a Word document that contains step-by-step instructions about our duties.

Along with that, I've created `CommandButtons` that, when clicked, create an email with the `.to`, `.subject` and `.HTMLBody` pre-populated.

By design, it does not send automatically - it will still need editing by the user.

There are circumstances where more recipients need to be added to the `.to` field.

I'd like another `CommandButton` in the Word document that will detect the already created (and open, but not necessarily 'on top') email and append the email address to the `.to` list.

```
'Global variables so I only have to update emails in one place
Public Group1 As String
Public Group2 As String
Public Group3 as String

'called to assign emails to global variables
Sub Contacts()

    Group1 = "name@email.com; name2@email.com; name3@email.com; "
    Group2 = "name4@email.com; name5@email.com; "
    Group3 = "newname@email.com; newname2@email.com; "

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton100_Click()

    Dim xOutlookObj As Object
    Dim OMail As Object
    Dim xEmail As Object
    Dim xDoc As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set xOutlookObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xEmail = xOutlookObj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Set xDoc = ActiveDocument

    'assign values to global variables
    Call Contacts

    With xEmail
        .Display
        .to = Group1 + Group2
        .Subject = "This is a Test"
        .HTMLBody = "<font face=""arial"" style=""font-size:11pt;"">" & _
            "body" & .HTMLBody & "</font>"
        'Side-note - the end of the above line is the only way I could figure out how to keep the Signature stored in Outlook. If there's a better way, I'm all ears!

    End With
    
    Set xDoc = Nothing
    Set xEmail = Nothing
    Set xOutlookObj = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The code opens an email with a template (not shown) and email addresses pre-populated.

How do I append the email addresses assigned to the Group3 variable to the end of the `.to` field?

Comment: Use `&` to concatenate, not `+`.

Comment: Duly noted. Believe it or not, I started with &, but had it in quotes. When that threw an error, tried the +. It worked, and I didn't look back. But I'll make the change - Thanks!

Comment: Does the subject line change? the reason I ask is, what if you have multiple email open and how do you identify which email to append Group3

Comment: The subject line will always be the same. I'll take a look at your solution - thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Work with [Inspectors object (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspectors) which has set of [Inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector) objects representing all inspectors*

*Now assuming your subject line stays the same then search by subject and add to Group3*

*Example*

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim Outlook_App As Object
    Set Outlook_App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Dim Inspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
    Set Inspectors = Outlook_App.Inspectors
    
    Call Contacts
    
    Dim i As Long
    If Inspectors.Count > 0 Then
        
        For i = Inspectors.Count To 1 Step -1
            
            If Inspectors.Item(i).CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
                Set Item = Inspectors.Item(i).CurrentItem
                
                If Item.Subject = "This is a Test" Then
                    Item.To = Item.To & ";" & Group3
                End If
                
            End If
            
        Next
        
    Else
        Debug.Print "No inspector windows are open."
    End If

End Sub
```

---

> *[Add reference to Outlook library in VBA Editor, Tools, References](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662697/4539709)*