# Find and put in italic a list of words (that are listed in a.txt file) in all my Outlook message

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I'm trying to find and put in italic a list of words (that are listed in the .txt file) in all my Outlook message.

I tried a Word VBA macro in Outlook (found it [here](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T013773_Changing_the_Color_of_a_List_of_Words.html)).

It works in Word.

In Outlook I get

> Run-time error 424, Object Required.

```vb
Sub ChangeWordColorsFile()
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    
    sFile = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\List words.txt"
    
    Open sFile For Input As 1
    
    While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, sTemp
        sTemp = Trim(sTemp)
    
        If sTemp > "" Then
            Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
            Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
            Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Italic = True
            With Selection.Find
                .Text = sTemp
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = True
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = True
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
            End With
            Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End If
    Wend
    Close #1
End Sub
```

Comment: `Selection` doesn't exist in Outlook. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to automatically find and put in italic a list of words (that are listed in the .txt file) in all my Outlook message

Comment: Do you have (or intend to have) an open Word application? I don't know if the [Outlook object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/outlook) has such find/replace capabilities. OTOH, if you can do it in the UI, you can probably do it from VBA. Can you do what you are trying to do in the Outlook UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To use it on Outlook see example below*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    
    Dim Inspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim Selection As Word.Selection

    Set Inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
    Set wdDoc = Inspector.WordEditor
    Set Selection = wdDoc.Application.Selection

    sFile = "D:\Temp\words.txt"

    Open sFile For Input As 1

    While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, sTemp
        sTemp = Trim(sTemp)

        If sTemp > "" Then
            Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
            Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
            Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Italic = True
            With Selection.Find
                .Text = sTemp
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Forward = True
                .wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = True
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = True
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
            End With
            Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End If
    Wend
    
    Close #1
End Sub
```

[***Make sure to Reference to Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662697/4539709)

***Code tested on [Application.ActiveInspector()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.activeinspector)***