# Format a pasted string or paragraph in Outlook as italic

Tags: vba, outlook, formatting, clipboard

I'm pasting plain text from a non-vba program into the middle of an existing Outlook message body that's in HTML format. I do have control of the text before it's copied, so I -could- include html tags (`<i></i>`) if that's required.   I need to format just this pasted text to italics once it's in outlook.  I'm struggling finding out how to do this.

I can't seem to just include `<i></i>` tags in the text before copying, and then set the .objMsg.HtmlBody to the text because that would set the entire message to the text.  And just pasting it gives me the tags as actual text, not live tags.

What might work is to select the text after pasting in Outlook and then format it, but I'm struggling there too--how would I just select the text I just pasted using Outlook VBA? I assume it would be based on the current cursor position after pasting, much like I might do in Word, but I don't see a way to do that kind of selection in Outlook.

Comment: [...put in italic a list of words...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64753929/find-and-put-in-italic-a-list-of-words-that-are-listed-in-a-txt-file-in-all-my)

Comment: thanks! But... this example seems to rely on text being selected in Outlook in order to apply the formatting, which won't be the case (unless there's some way way to select text through VBA in Outlook after pasting it?)

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the `MailItem` class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately.
3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.